# Can't Uninstall External Hard Drive, and I Can't See it in Disk Management

Tags: windows-10, drivers, external-hard-drive

I'm trying to fix an external hard drive for a customer; however, I can only see it in device manager, and I can't uninstall it from device manager (it's been attempting for about 3 hours).  I've tried about 3 different USB ports, and nothing.

Updating the driver software did nothing.  Doe anyone have any ideas?

Comment: By "uninstall" you mean eject or something else; edit your question

Comment: @Ramhound By uninstall I mean by uninstalling from the device manager.  Question edited.

Comment: @Ramhound..... if you right click on a device in Device Manage you have an option to "uninstall". The problem is that uninstalling won't work because it is still physically plugged in. It is a legitimate question but he might just need a little more guidance... – ZiggyStardust 16 mins ago

Answer (score 0):

I am going to take a guess and say you should probably be using Disk Management and not Device Manager. Disk Management is where you can assign drive letters to USB drives and partition/format them. The word fix is a little too nebulous. What exactly is the problem with the drive?

Comment: I can't see it in the disk management.  So I can't format it.  That's why I tried to uninstall it from Device Manager.

Comment: If you can't see it in Disk Management it isn't being recognized as a hard drive. What does it show up as (and where) in device manager and is there a yellow exclamation through it? Device Manager won't do you much good. USB drives are either their or they aren't. (or have a yellow exclamation which would mean it needs further investigation). Can you see it in My Computer (does it show up as anything)?

Comment: It's showing up as Seagate Expansion SCSI Disk Device.  Without any yellow exclamation mark.

Comment: It doesn't show up in either My Computer or Disk Management? It isn't off the screen so you have to scroll down to see it?

Comment: It isn't on either.

Comment: I have always been a little fuzzy about the difference between a normal USB drive and an Expansion drive. Still don't really understand the difference. One way or the other see if Seagate has any utility software for it. Look here: http://www.seagate.com/support/by-product/software-and-apps/

Comment: I have always been a little fuzzy on the difference between a normal USB drive and an Expansion drive. One way or the other look for utility software for it at Seagate: http://www.seagate.com/support/by-product/software-and-apps/ It might requited special software to get it to be recognized as a drive. What is the model number?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49530/discussion-between-thomas-hutton-and-ziggystardust).

Comment: I am going to say the drive is dead at this point. What you are seeing in Device Manager is the SATA to USB adapter but the drive behind it is dead. That's the reason you can't uninstall it from device manager.

Answer (score 0):

Try to format usb device with [HP USB Disk Storage Format Tool](http://descargar.cnet.com/HP-USB-Disk-Storage-Format-Tool/3000-2094_4-10974082.html) (run with administrative privileges and choose the correct partition (fat32 or ntfs)